# How do I lazy-load a config from an initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apartment-gem, money-rails

I'm using Rails 6 with the 'money-rails' gem (for multiple currencies) and 'apartment' gem (for multi-tenancy). In the 'money-rails' documentation it is said that I could lazy-load the configuration of the default currency of the app, by using doing something like this:

```
# config/initializers/money.rb
MoneyRails.configure do |config|

  # set the default currency based on client configuration
  config.default_currency = -> { Tenant.current.default_currency }
end
```

I have a `Tenant` model with a `default_currency` column. But, if I try to use something like this example, I get an 'method missing error', probably because the class Tenant is not loaded yet and it's not possible to find a current tenant. What is the best way round this problem?

```
`method_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached' for Tenant:Class (NoMethodError)
```

[This is the money-rails documentation](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails).